# Why can't my Anaconda python install find a package added to a conda env via pip?

Tags: anaconda

Platform is MacOS Sierra, w/latest Anaconda python 3.6. `/Users/[me]`replaced with `${HOME}` in all the output below.

I'm testing some scripts that use the Auth0 python SDK. I created a new conda environment for my testing. The Auth0 module is not available in any conda channel that I am aware of so I used pip from the new conda environment (after having activate that environment):

```
$ source ${HOME}/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/activate
(root) $ ${HOME}/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/pip install auth0-python

(root) $ which python    
${HOME}/anaconda/bin/python
(root) $ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '${HOME}/anaconda/lib/python36.zip', 
'${HOME}/anaconda/lib/python3.6', '${HOME}/anaconda/lib/python3.6/lib-
dynload', '${HOME}/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
'${HOME}/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
'${HOME}/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa']
```

I can see the auth0-python module in that environment in Anaconda Navigator and from the command line:

```
$ ${HOME}/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/pip show auth0-python
Name: auth0-python
Version: 3.1.4
Summary: Auth0 Python SDK
Home-page: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-python
Author: Auth0
Author-email: support@auth0.com
License: MIT
Location: ${HOME}/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: requests
(root) 
$
```

but python is not finding it:

```
$ source ${HOME}/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/activate
(root) 
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “test.py", line 12, in <module>
    from auth0.v3.authentication import GetToken
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auth0'
(root) 
$
```

Comment: What is the output of `which python` just before you run the `test.py` script? Also, what is the output of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)`?

Comment: Added `which` and `sys.path` to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not specifying an environment name to the `activate` command. You can see this because you're using the pip in `anaconda3/envs/python3/bin`, but the Python interpreter is from `anaconda3/bin`. Therefore, you're installing the package to the environment at `anaconda3/envs/python3`, but running the Python from the root environment (`anaconda3`).

To fix this, simply specify the environment name to the `activate` script:

```
source ${HOME}/anaconda3/bin/activate python3
```

Also, if you have `anaconda3/bin` on your PATH, you don't need to specify the full path to the activation script.